# depth of kinect

Tags: ros, depth

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I use the ununtu and openni.

I'm looking at the kinect depth value.

(http://www.ros.org/wiki/kinect_calibration/technical).

There is "Disparity to depth relationship".

Is it open-kinect or openni or both relationship?

I want to know depth value and compare the actual distance.

(http://mathnathan.com/2011/02/depthvsdistance/)

The hompage' host used libfreenect driver.

Can anyone tell me how to obtain depth value or disparity value in ubuntu, openni

driver?

Is it possible extract the distance or disparity in a particular point ?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40605/depth-of-kinect/) by [ha](https://answers.ros.org/users/2979/ha/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-08-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can get the distance values out using the PointCloud interface.  For technical details on disparity to depth calibration see the [kinect_calibration](http://www.ros.org/wiki/kinect_calibration/technical) wiki page.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-01-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0